# Ruby on Rails remote create form with popup show partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm a RoR junior and I'm making online shop app, so:

- on the show view of product I have remote form for `@line_item`
- in the show action of products_controller I have `@line_item = LineItem.new`
- I have `create.js.erb` file in `views/line_items`
- My create action of `line_items_controller` looks like this:

  `respond_to do |format|
    format.js { }
  end`

**QUESTION:** How to make a popup window with line_item's details information appearing when line item's create form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that line in the controller there - all you need is to trigger the display of a popup inside your create.js.erb. That js file will be rendered by convention after executing the create controller method because it is an asynchronous call.

Comment: So, I dont't need to write format.js block? Just call modal window and append it to some dom in the view in create.js.erb file?

Comment: That's correct! The format stuff will only be used when you append a ".js" to your url. But that doesn't have to do with the rendering of your javascript file. You can remove that format block entirely, it will still work.